Azure DevOps Pipeline resource triggers
I am attempting to run one Azure pipeline after another finishes. After reading the Microsoft documentation I have implemented the following 2 pipelines. However the second pipeline does not trigger when the first has completed
Here is the yml file for the source pipeline
Also the name for this in the Azure DevOps pipelines page is: Source Pipeline
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger: none

jobs:
  - job: test
    displayName: 'Test'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
      - checkout: none
      - script: |
          #!/bin/bash
          set -e
          echo 'Test'
        displayName: 'Test'

And here is the pipeline that should run automatically when this above one completes:
The name for this one in the Pipelines page is: Test for Pipeline Resource Trigger
# https://aka.ms/yaml


trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: 'Test'
      source: 'Source Pipeline'
      trigger: true

jobs:
  - job: test
    displayName: 'Test'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
      - checkout: none
      - script: |
          #!/bin/bash
          echo 'Test'
        displayName: 'Test'

I was expecting Test for Pipeline Resource Trigger to run after the completion of Source Pipeline however despite numerous attempts with various syntaxes as well as moving the pipelines out of pipeline folders I have had no luck.
Any tips on what I could be doing wrong would be appreciated!
Thanks.

What is the type of repository? git, github, githubenterprise, or bitbucket?

Also, are these pipelines in the same project?

You might also need to run the second pipeline manually to authorize resources that might be used by the pipeline - see Authorize a YAML pipeline

To answer some questions. Its all in Azure DevOps, they are in the same project and I have manually ran the second pipeline to authorize resources. In fact I believe it would prompt me to do this if the trigger had worked

Turns out this post was the solution to my particular issue, you live and learn... 
I suspect it was not triggering as my yaml files are currently not in the default branch (main) and are still on seperate branches,
Azure Pipeline Triggers in Azure Devops: Trigger a pipeline when another completes not working as expected

Your sample works fine. I`ve tested on one repo and builds in the root folder.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. Can you [edit] your answer to summarize the relevant guidance from the link? Answers on Stack Overflow can certainly link to additional information, but they should stand on their own even if the page they are linking to is later (re)moved. This is important because often, over time, the linked pages are no longer available, which is frustrating for future members of the community.
